# ¿Como se interpreta el @forelse en laravel y para que sirve?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Quisiera que me ayudasen a entender de que forma se aplica el `@forelse` en [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Es lo mismo que un foreach, pero en caso que el parámetro de entrada esté vacío, mostrará lo que esté entre `@empty` y `@endforelse`.

El objetivo de `@forelse` es reducir el código necesario para hacer:

```
@if ($users->count())
  @foreach ($users as $user)
    <p>Usuario {{ $user->id }}</p>
  @endforeach
@else
  <p>No hay usuarios.</p>
@endif
```

a esto:

```
@forelse ($users as $user)
    <p>Usuario {{ $user->id }}</p>
@empty
    <p>No hay usuarios.</p>
@endforelse
```

En caso que quieras ver como se hace la compilación de Blade: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/View/Compilers/Concerns/CompilesLoops.php#L14

Answer (score 1):

Con un ejemplo se entiende, simplemente recorre todos los valores del array/collection que le pases y si esta vacio salta el else.

```
@forelse($array as $objeto_individual)
   <h1> {{ $objeto_individual }}</h1>
@empty
   <h1> Sin valores </h1>
@forelse
```

Answer (score 1):

Para complementar la respuesta de @Shaz :

El `forelse` no solo verifica si la variable esta vacía, sino también si esta seteada, es decir valida `"empty"` e `"isset"`.