# Condición WHERE en Laravel

Tags: laravel

estoy sacando datos de la base de datos en laravel. Bien realizo esta `Route` para que me haga un foreach donde `status` sea = a `0`.

```
Route::get('/admin', function () {
        $presupuestos = Presupuesto::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get()->where('status', 0);
        return view('admin.index', compact('presupuestos'));
    })->name('admin');
```

El problema es que si en la tabla no hay ninguno con `status` = `0` me devuelve error.

Comment: Entonces el valor de 0 es opcional para tu consulta no?

Comment: Digamos que si, lo utilizo para que en el foreach me muestre solo las filas que tienen valor 0

Comment: espera me acabo de dar cuenta que es por el AJAX que tengo con esa variable, por que en otros datos aunq no hay uno con valor 0 si funciona

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Como se interpreta el @forelse en laravel y para que sirve?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/85889/como-se-interpreta-el-forelse-en-laravel-y-para-que-sirve)

Comment: Opino que si quieres controlar si tu consulta trae resultados haga un foreach y si no avise que no hay datos, lo que Shaz respondió en ese enlace te sirve

Comment: Si es una buena opción, pero creo que el problema es del AJAX al solicitar peticion y no existir me viene error en la url del AJAX, una cosa @BetaM ahora tengo más claro lo de la actualización a través de ajax, que estuviste respondiendome antes en otro post, podemos trasladar al chat alli?