# Cómo representar un error: ErrorException Trying to get property para un condicional

Tags: laravel

Tengo una collección de datos y de todos los datos solo hay una coincidencia, no sé como manejar este error: `ErrorException Trying to get property` yo hago un `@if ($offer->user->profile->photo == NULL)` pero no lo valida, me imagino que no es un valor NULL, tampoco funciona con `@if ($offers->isEmpty())`

Lo que necesito lograr es que si no hay datos imprima una imagen por defecto y en caso contrario la que está en la BD, con `dd($offers[1]->user->profile->photo);` en el controlador verifico que existe la foto y me da la ruta.

```
@forelse ($offers as $offer)
    @if ($offer->user->profile->photo == NULL)
        <img class="rounded-circle" src="{{ asset("img/app/users/default.jpg") }}"></a>
    @else
        <img class="rounded-circle" src="{{ $offer->user->profile->photo }}"></a>
    @endif

@empty

@endforelse
```

Comment: Estas usando de modo incorrecto `forelse` que de hecho sería la solución en este caso,

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Como se interpreta el @forelse en laravel y para que sirve?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/85889/como-se-interpreta-el-forelse-en-laravel-y-para-que-sirve)

Comment: Disculpa, borré el @empty para la pregunta, porque era muy largo el contenido... Igual no funciona

Comment: Trara de seguir la sintaxis del ciclo en cuestión y en caso de que no funcione trata de dar mejor contexto por que al momento la pregunta puede terminar cerrada como duplicado

Comment: También dispones en los helpers, del uso de [optional](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-optional)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes intentar de la siguiente manera:

- Utilizando `@isset()`, ver la documentación [aquí](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade):

  ```
  @isset($offer->user->profile->photo)

  @endisset
  ```

Si aún así no te funciona, probablemente el atributo `photo` no está llegando, y deberás utilizar la [función](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists) de PHP llamada `property_exists()`