# Solventar error con tablas relacionadas

Tags: laravel

Tengo dos tablas relacionadas `Users` y `Profiles`, ambas guardan información del `usuario`, pero hago el registro en dos partes, los primeros datos (`email` y `password`) se guardan en la tabla `Users` y el `usuario` debe confirmar el `email` para continuar, una vez que lo hace lo lleva a un formulario para completar el perfil.

El problema se presenta cuando el usuario hace el primer paso (Completar el email y password) la tabla `profiles` no tiene el user_id porque no se ha completado el paso dos y a veces puede tardar en hacerlo, cuando entro como administrador me muestra un error:

```
Trying to get property 'name' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\web.com\resources\views\admin\dashboard\users\admin-index.blade.php)
```

Ese error lo muestra porque no ha encontrado los datos, este es mí código:

```
$users = User::join('profiles', 'profiles.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                    ->where('users.user_type', '!=', 'Super')
                    ->where('users.status', '!=', 'DELETED')
                    ->where('users.status', '!=', 'REGISTERED')
                    ->orderBy('users.id', 'DESC')
                    ->paginate(15);
```

Como podría decirle al controlador que obvie esos registros? sé que puedo colocar las variables como opcionales en la vista `{{ $user->profile->name ?? '' }}`, pero en el administrador me aparece el registro sin mostrar los datos y no lo veo como una solución óptima.

Comment: Si es posible que la consulta no devuelva datos, no sería mas sencillo usar un forelse en la vista?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Como se interpreta el @forelse en laravel y para que sirve?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/85889/como-se-interpreta-el-forelse-en-laravel-y-para-que-sirve)

Comment: el problema es que está el registrode quien no haya completado el perfil, pero si está registrado en la tabla `User` asociado a un `join` por el campo `user_id`, cuando listo los registros me aparecen sin nombre, en caso de poner la varible como opcional. Me gustaría que cuando pase eso me elimine de la consulta ese registro.

Answer (score 0):

No estoy del todo seguro, pero al hacer join estas actuando sobre la base de datos sin pasar por el modelo de eloquent por lo cual ese campo no existe, por que es explicito de la query, al usar eloquent este traerá incluso los fillables sin datos.

```html
//User Class

public function profile(){
    return $this->hasOne(Profile::class)
}

// controller

$users = User::with('profile')
    ->where('user_type', '<>', 'Super')
    ->where('status', '<>', 'DELETED')
    ->where('status', '<>', 'REGISTERED')
    ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
    ->paginate(15);
```

Comment: Yo no veo como hacer carga ambiciosa solicionará este problema, ya que la query del OP es correcta, un with no es un join, el with no le funcionará sino usa modelos y menos aún si no ha definido las relaciones, la consulta se puede hacer omitiendo los modelos y aún así funcionar

Comment: De hecho tu consulta le va a generar otro problema, el `with` estaría cargando tanto a usuarios con perfil como aquellos que no lo tienen, en todo caso te falta el método `has` al inicio para hacer un `WHERE EXISTS` y lograr filtrar solo aquellos usuarios cuyo `id` si aparezca como llave foránea en alguna fila de la tabla `perfiles`