# ¿Cómo corregir el error Trying to get property?

Tags: laravel, foreach

estoy intentando recibir info de laravel

```
public function index()
    {
        $website   = app(\Hyn\Tenancy\Environment::class)->website();
 
        $websiteId = $website->id;

        $fields=Field::where('uui', $website->id)
               ->get();

        return view('adm.fields')->with('fields',$fields);
        
    }
```

en blade tengo

```
@foreach($fields as $field)
                                    <tr class="no-b">
                                        <td class="w-10">
                                            <img src="storage/images/{!! $field->image !!}" alt="">
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <h6>{!! $field->name !!}</h6>
                                            <small class="text-muted">{!! $field->category !!}</small>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>{!! $field->width !!}</td>
                                        <td>{!! $field->length !!}</td>
                                        <td><span class="badge badge-success">{!! $field->status !!}</span></td>
                                        <td>{!! $field->description !!}</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <a class="btn-fab btn-fab-sm btn-primary shadow text-white" href="/fields/{!! $field->id !!}/edit"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    @endforeach
```

Mi problema es que si el foreach no tiene un registro, muestra el error `Trying to get property 'id' of non-object`...

y yo estoy intentando que si no muestra info diga "No hay informacion aun"

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Como se interpreta el @forelse en laravel y para que sirve?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/85889/como-se-interpreta-el-forelse-en-laravel-y-para-que-sirve)

Answer (score 0):

lo solucione de la siguiente manera, en lugar de usar un foreach...

use un forelse, que cumple la misma funcion que el foreach pero se puede condicionar, en este caso si esta recibiendo información nula.

```
@forelse ($fields as $field)
                                        <tr class="no-b">
                                            <td class="w-10">
                                                <img src="storage/images/{!! $field->image !!}" alt="">
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <h6>{!! $field->name !!}</h6>
                                                <small class="text-muted">{!! $field->category !!}</small>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>{!! $field->width !!}</td>
                                            <td>{!! $field->length !!}</td>
                                            <td><span class="badge badge-success">{!! $field->status !!}</span></td>
                                            <td>{!! $field->description !!}</td>
                                            <td>
                                                <a class="btn-fab btn-fab-sm btn-primary shadow text-white" href="/fields/{!! $field->id !!}/edit"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        @empty
    
                                            <p class="bg-danger text-white p-1">No product</p>
                                        @endforelse
```

Comment: Si bien podría ser una solución, sería oportuno que el OP traduzca su pregunta a español primero, ya que de otra manera esta terminará cerrada

Comment: Te recomiendo leas [answer]

Comment: Tu respuesta es solo codigo. Por favor mira [answer]. Se pide que expliques que hace este código (mas alla que a ti vos te parezca obvio, puede que otro usuario no lo vea tan simple). Tambien, las preguntas en otro idioma distinto al oficial no deben responderse...

Comment: Hola, ya lo resolvi y publique la respuesta, perdon estaba en ingles no me di cuenta no se porque entre a al stack en español siempre voy al de ingles jaja

Comment: Bueh, ya ves que también hay opción en español!